# Spawning Multiple Java Processes

Tags: java, command-prompt, processbuilder, spawn

I need to write a simple java program, wherein I create another process using ProcessBuilder class.

`String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "start", "java Tester3"};
 ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( command );`

Here, "Tester3" is the name of the java program that i want to run as a separate process.Now I am not sure about what the code does but I guess it opens a new command prompt and runs the Tester3 program inside it. Now, if I have certain System.out.println() statements inside Tester3, how can I make the newly created command prompt for spawned process display these statements. As of now, when I just run these two lines, I see a separate command prompt being created with no output on it. How can I achieve the display of output for Tester3 in the command prompt where it is being run?

Comment: ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec() are very hard to use in java ,they don't quite work as if u just use windows cmd , give this a read http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html , very important article about this issue

Comment: @vlatkozelka That article is **fourteen** years old.  ProcessBuilder works superbly now and certainly is not "very hard to use."  Now, if your point was that there are some difficulties when using ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec to run a Windows program with `cmd /c start`, I am inclined to agree with you.

Comment: If you want to run another Java process with no console in Windows, try `new ProcessBuilder("javaw.exe", "Tester3")`.  From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html): “The javaw command is identical to java, except that with javaw there is no associated console window. Use javaw when you do not want a command prompt window to appear.”  Or, of course, you could call `Tester3.main(new String[0])` directly in your code.